# Can't stop while loop in script

Tags: perl, timeout

I've wrote super simple script that rotate trough my logs files and tail them, endlessly.

My problem that I can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> this program and I need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and kill it after.

How can I solve this ?
I've tried with perl, but I have a msg "alarm clock" that I want to avoid.
with perl i could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it fine.

```
perl -e "alarm 10; exec @ARGV" "tail -15f $line | filter"
```

And my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
    #
    while :
    do while read line
            do
                    charcount=$(ls $line | awk '{ print length; }')
                    printf '%0.s=' $(seq 1 $charcount)
                    echo -e "\n$line"
                    printf '%0.s=' $(seq 1 $charcount)
                    printf '\n'
                    timeout 10s tail -15f $line | filter
            done < <(ls /var/log/net/*.log)
    done
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? I suspect you're just causing pain for yourself by building in timeouts and alarms in two different languages. I would suggest reimplementing in pure perl.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Alarm Clock' alert you refer to is because that's the default way of handling a `SIGALRM` signal, generated by the `alarm` function in perl.

The usual reason why `Ctrl-C` doesn't work, is because there's a blocking call occuring, and so the `SIGINT` signal sent doesn't get caught and handled. I can't see anything obvious in your code that would be causing this though.

To my mind, the most obvious way is - stop mixing perl and bash, because that way lies madness.

How about using the [`File::Tail`](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-1.0/Tail.pm) module in Perl? This even has an example of how to do what you're wanting:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Tail;

foreach (@ARGV) {
    push( @files, File::Tail->new( name => "$_", debug => $debug ) );
}
while (1) {
    ( $nfound, $timeleft, @pending ) =
        File::Tail::select( undef, undef, undef, $timeout, @files );
    unless ($nfound) {

        # timeout - do something else here, if you need to
    }
    else {
        foreach (@pending) {
            print $_->{"input"} . " ("
                . localtime(time) . ") "
                . $_->read;
        }
    }
}
```

This will probably allow you to `ctrl-c` whilst running it anyway, but Perl does allow you to have better control over signals via the [`%SIG`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) hash - allowing you to define custom handlers for kill signals - such as `SIGALRM` from `alarm` and `SIGINT` from `Ctrl-C`.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with perl, Thanks for the info, I'll check this out.